# C# Dynamic generic instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

This is my first question here and i'm not very familliar with the C# terminology, so if i get some terms or definitions mixed up i appologize in advance.

I have set up a generic EF data access layer;

```
public class BaseService<TObject> where TObject : class
{
    private DbContext Context;
    private static readonly Lazy<BaseService<TObject>> lazy = new Lazy<BaseService<TObject>>(() => new BaseService<TObject>());
    public static BaseService<TObject> Instance => lazy.Value;

    public BaseService()
    {
        Context = new evEntities();
    }

    public BaseService(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public ICollection<TObject> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TObject>().ToList();
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<TObject>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await Context.Set<TObject>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public TObject Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TObject>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

Together with this;

```
public static class DA
{
    public static DataAccess.Categories Categories => new DataAccess.Categories();
    public static DataAccess.Tags Tags => new DataAccess.Tags();
    public static DataAccess.Users Users => new DataAccess.Users();
}

public static class DA<T> where T : class
{
    public static BaseService<T> Base => new BaseService<T>();
}
```

So in my Business Layer i can do this;

```
public class Categories
{
    public Categories() { }

    public ICollection<Database.Categories> GetAll()
    {
        return DA.Categories.GetAll().ToList();
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<Database.Categories>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await DA.Categories.GetAllAsync();
    }

    public Database.Categories Get(int id)
    {
        return DA.Categories.Get(id);
    }
}
```

For clarity. My EF creates classes/entities like 'Database.Categories' and 'Database.Users' which i pass as 'TObject' to my **BaseService** to get a standard way of pulling data from my database for all my entities.

Now my question. In a similar way i want to create a generic Business Layer. Like;

```
public class BusinessLogicBase<TModel>
{
    public ICollection<TDBModel> GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<TDBModel>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await DA.Categories.GetAllAsync();
    }

    public TDBModel Get(int id)
    {
        return DA.Categories.Get(id);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the DA with a TObject like Database.Categories but this has to be dynamic, based on the type passed to the BusinessLogicBase. So i want to do something like this (which doesn't work);

```
private ???? DetermineDatabaseModel()
{
    switch(typeof(TModell))
    {
        case Models.Categories:
            return Database.Categories;
        case Models.Users:
            return Database.Users;
    }
}
```

So i can do this;

```
public ICollection<TDBModel> GetAll()
{
    var databaseModel = DetermineDatabaseModel()
    return DA<databaseModel>().GetAll();
}
```

I hope you understand my question and can help me.

Thnx!

Sorry for the long post, and for all you 9gaggers, here's a potato... No just kidding, this is serious.

Comment: You could leave most of the EF part away as your beef is "How do I tell computer to treat two types the same that are in no way related to each other than that they are the same *to me*". You could just use AutoMapper to map the properties assuming both TModel and TObject have same properties.

Comment: Hi Janne, that;s not completly true. I know they are not the same, and i'm not trying to convince the computer to see them as the same. I want to have a function to return the data type to use as a generic, based on a passed generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
public class BusinessLogicBase<TDBModel> where TDBModel : class {
  public ICollection<TDBModel> GetAll() {
    return DA<TDBModel>.Base.GetAll();
  }
}
```

### UPDATE 1:

**Maybe it would help You if you try to write it without generics first and then convert it into more general pattern using generics. There are some missteps that are easier to solve without generics.**

Method `public ICollection<TDBModel> GetAll()` can't return `ICollection<TDBModel>` because type parameter `TDBModel` is not defined either in class signature or method signature. I makes more sense if you define it like this:

```
public class BusinessLogicBase<TModel>
{
    public ICollection<TModel> GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2:

try [this simple console app](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RMAp4f) to demonstrate `dynamic` keyword and watch what is stored in variables `categories` and `users`.

### UPDATE 3:

Based on fiddle - I've changed `IBaseService<dynamic>` to `dynamic`:

```
public class BL<TModel>
{
    // This is what i want to make dynamic.
    // how do i create a return type that i can use in DA<>..
    private Type testDetermineDatabaseModel()
    {
        switch(typeof(TModel).Name){
            case "Categories":
                return typeof(Database.Categories);
            case "Users":
                return typeof(Database.Users);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ICollection<TModel> testGetAll() 
    {
        var databaseModel = testDetermineDatabaseModel();
        // return DA<databaseModel>().Base.GetAll();
        return new List<TModel>();
    }

    // NEW
    // I have constructed the following.
    private dynamic  baseService;

    public dynamic DetermineDatabaseModel()
    {
        switch (typeof(TModel).Name)
        {
            case "Categories":
                return new BaseService<Database.Categories>();
            case "Users":
                return new BaseService<Database.Users>();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private IBaseService<TDbModel> GetBase<TDbModel>() where TDbModel : class
    {
        return new BaseService<TDbModel>();
    }

    public ICollection<TModel> GetAll()
    {

        ICollection<TModel> returnValue = new List<TModel>();
        // This works!!!
        foreach (var item in GetBase<Database.Categories>().GetAll())
        {
            returnValue.Add((TModel)(object)item);
        }

        baseService = DetermineDatabaseModel();
        // This doesn't!!! It's the same thing!! :(
        foreach (var item in baseService.GetAll())
        {
            returnValue.Add((TModel)(object)item);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

But remember, this not solve the issue You are facing. That is map 2 generic types.

Comment: Hi Dolphin, Yes i did, but i do not want to pass the Database objects when calling the BLL.

Comment: Hi, so basically you only want to know how DetermineDatabaseModel method should look like ? In that case i will update answer tomorrow.

Comment: Yes :D Thnx! I will eagerly await your answer :D

Comment: I still don't understand why static generic DA<> couldn't be used. If you insist on using method "DetermineDatabaseModel" you have to use reflection - You can't return type parameter with method, but you can return type itself typeof(TDBModel) return type will be "System.Type".

Comment: I tried that, but i then get an error: <b>'databaseModel' is a variable but is used as a type.</b>. I altered DetermineDatabaseModel to return <b>typeof(Database.Categories)</b>. I'm not dead set on using this method, do you have suggestions?

Comment: Signature of method will look like this "private System.Type DetermineDatabaseModel()", and you will return from method this: return typeof(Database.Users); //that will get type of class. Then you will use returned type to dynamically create instance of class you need with reflection.

Comment: Also can you use interface ? Lets say all of your "BaseService<TObject>" will implement interface IBaseService that has method GetAll() so then you can simply return IBaseService from DetermineDatabaseModel and call method that you need.

Comment: I tried using as Interface, but the Interface will still have <TDBModel> which i need to determine.

Comment: How would i use reflection to use the typeof(Database.Users) in my DA<> call?

Comment: Ok, i finally get it :D But the problem is that compiler doesn't know TDBModel at compile time in BusinessLogicBase<TModel> - so you cannot return it with method unless you specify type parameter in class signature or method signature (or establish some mapping). Try to post me how would final usage of Your BusinessLogicBase<TModel> look like.

Comment: From the controller i would like to do somthing like this `BL<Model.Categories>().GetAll()`.

Comment: yes, but you want to get from `BL<Model.Categories>().GetAll()` result in `ICollection<Database.Categories>` am i right ?

Comment: Yes, Thats what i want.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible - it doesn't make much sense, you cannot say give me "oranges" and expect to get "apples". But if you insist, you can use boxing/unboxing or dynamic keyword - I've updated answer.

Comment: I created following [netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1DWrgw), please change it accordingly so we can test/implement your solution. Some mock data would be nice :)

Comment: Thnx Dolphin, for setting up the test! I've added some code, is it saved automaticly? I have no idea how to return a list with some data :(

Comment: Nope i does not save automatically :) You have to sign up and save it manually.

Comment: No luck :( Still i cant see what you saved, could you simplify your question into simple console app where you demonstrate your issue and then update it ? I will delete my answer and post new..

Comment: Excusses for the delay, working hard and busy social life ;) I think i've solved my problem!! At least..it builds :D Take a look at the final piece of code, starting at line 123: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4OZ972

Comment: I've updated answer, now its should work. Don't forget to mark answer as correct if it solves Your issue - and remember this should be solved on architecture level, not by code syntax...